# The type org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, javabeans

The type `org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext` cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required `.class` files

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import edu.onetwofour.bean.CalculatorBean;

public class SpringTestmain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("edu.onetwofour");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `org.springframework.context` and `org.springframework.context.support` dependencies (jar) to your spring project.

The class `org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext` is available in these jars.